# How to use a function from VB.NET's My in C#?

Tags: c#, vb.net, c#-to-vb.net

I was writing some C# code and going off of a VB.NET example. The example used the function

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.GetDirectories()
```

How can I use this function in C#?

Comment: **[Suggested reading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getdirectories?view=net-7.0)**

Comment: I think that answered my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be reluctant to use "VisualBasic" functionality in C# that exists in DotNet itself.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.filesystem.getdirectories?view=net-6.0#definition

In the above link, note these:

```
Namespace:
Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO
Assembly:
Microsoft.VisualBasic.Core.dll
```

Pulling those references into a C# "feels wrong". (I'm sure people do it sometimes).

But here is the better option:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getdirectories?view=net-6.0#system-io-directory-getdirectories(system-string)

```
Namespace:
System.IO
Assembly:
System.Runtime.dll
```

and the available methods:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getdirectories?view=net-6.0#overloads